# STL analogue in Fortran

Tags: c++, stl, fortran

**Basis:** i have very big parallel Fortran90/MPI program which represent complex physical model. I want to add new functionality to it: for example, i need to organize queue of messages, introduce mergesort somewhere and use hash tables.

**Problem:** i know how write hash table, create queue and code mergesort by my self, but i don't think it is a good idea to invent a bicycle.

**Question:** what Fortran guru should do in such situation? Should i build binds to C++ classes from Fortran and realize logic there using STL or you can suggest some Fortran STL-like libraries? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no templates in Fortran and hence no STL. You can try [FLIBS](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/) for some generic libraries. It generally uses `transfer()` tricks to achieve generic programming.

There is a preprocessor which adds some templates to Fortran and comes with some small STL, you can try that too named [PyF95++](http://blockit.sourceforge.net/). If you have access to academic papers through some library, you can read about it [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1753167).

I would avoid mixing it with C++ in this specific case although it can be done. You must instantiate each case separately and interface it to Fortran using a wrapper (`bind(C)` and `iso_c_binding`). Only if you have a very limited number of types you want to use the algorithms for it could be worth it.

You can also try to implement some poor-man's templates using the C-preprocessors in Fortran, For smaller libraries it works, but can become too difficult to maintain or ugly for complex things. As an example you can see my implementation of a linked list https://github.com/LadaF/fortran-list .

Generally, there is no clearly right approach or answer, you always have to choose from more possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about encapsulation of new logic in C++, because it looks like more 'modern' way and i think about health of future developers) But I never heart about FLIBS: is it well-documented, bugs-free and supported code?

Comment: FLIBS is more or less a one man show of Arjen Markus but is quite well tested. Regarding what is modern, if C++ or Fortran I will not comment at all. Obviously I am a Fortran developer, because I like it. You opinion may be different.

Comment: I like Fortran too, but i should think not in terms of emotions but in terms of robust code. I tried FLIBS example just now and I am impressed by ease of integration. Do you know why last release of a such convenient library was in 2008?

Comment: According to this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/flibs/ the last update  was in 2013. Anyway you could ask the author, he is active on the comp.lang.fortran usenet list and I believe he will be open to your e-mail questions or even patches and enhancements.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to everything that Vladimir F already mentioned, there is now also the [Fortran Template Library](https://github.com/robertrueger/ftl) (FTL). Much of the FTL is a reimplementation of C++'s STL in Fortran, where the C preprocessor is abused for template instantiation. You have to instatiate your templates manually, but otherwise it should be quite convenient from the end user perspective. The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/robertrueger/ftl/wiki).

The library is still fairly new and while it comes with a lot of unit tests, it hasn't seen much use in the wild yet. You'll also need a very recent Fortran compiler to use it.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.