# Does Fortran have a priority queue?

Tags: fortran, priority-queue

I've used a number of computer languages and have grown used to common data structures being provided via standard libraries for the programmer. I'm 1337 enough to implement these myself, but recognize that having a single, standardized data structure implementation improves code readability and portability, while reducing the chance of bugs.

Now I'm working with Fortran, and I'm looking for such a library. Googling for "priority queue" coupled with C++ or Python brings up nice documentation of nice libraries. Doing the same with Fortran brings up RosettaCode and some site from 1997 as the top two results.

Does Fortran have a priority queue? Or any library of standard data structures?

Comment: The name of the language is Fortran.  It's been Fortran since ISO/IEC 1539:1991 became an International standard.  As to a library, you may want to check out FLIBS (yes, that is all caps) and the fortranwiki.org site.

Comment: This is perhaps closely related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24979199/3157076).  In short: there is no such "intrinsic" library for Fortran.

Comment: It is easy to conceptualise an Array of Structures (AoS). Fortran historically worked best on a structure of arrays. Particularly it allows vectorisation better, than pulling out every nth element of the AoS. There is nothing as easy for the compiler as an array for each structure element.